# How to create Recent Documents History in C# in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, recent-documents

I am making a WPF Application in C# where I need to show the recent documents history (just like it happens in word, excel and even visual studio), showing the list the last 5 or 10 documents opened. I have absolutely no idea as to how I should go about it. Please help. And please be kind and gentle...I am an amatuer coder, and it is tough to digest high-tech talks as of now! :)

Comment: Did you check [MRUManager](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mru.aspx) class?

Comment: Like I said....I am an amateur coder....please help me understand the MRUManager class and what it does. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the codeproject article I linked?

Comment: Did you see the word WPF in the OP?

Answer (score 10):

[JumpList in WPF4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.jumplist.aspx) is awesome. This was all I needed to do:

```
<Application 
    x:Class="MyApp"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    <Application.Resources>
    </Application.Resources>
    <JumpList.JumpList>
        <JumpList ShowRecentCategory="True"/>
    </JumpList.JumpList>
</Application>
```

Comment: What are the JumpList for WinForm?

Comment: @kmc Because JumpList (the code shown) displays a list of Most Recent Used documents, you webby ;)

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something, but this just creates a jump list and says to include the Recent category (Which is the default JumpList you get for free anyway).  This does nothing for showing the Recent items IN the application?

Comment: This initializes the jump list but doesn't do anything with it. At the very least one must also invoke e.g. `AddToRecentCategory()` and `Apply()` whenever a file should be recorded as recent. Additionally, this information is only available in the Windows taskbar, not within the application itself.

Comment: Here is a more complete jump list answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25542492/482758.

Answer (score 4):

This has a pretty nice walk through and sample

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/RecentFileList.aspx

Its good that it has both an xml file and registry store.

Answer (score 3):

My idea of solving this problem (as a beginner) was to retain all the file paths into a Queue of given maximum capacity and adding them at run-time into a menuItem...

Answer (score 2):

You could just keep a list of the documents that the user opens. Store the list when the program exits and load it when the program launches. You could probably store a list of things in the program settings, or you could write it to a file (plain text or xml would work ok).

You'd have to create the submenu for "recent documents" dynamically by keeping a reference to the "recent documents" `MenuItem`, then adding and removing `MenuItem`s from its `Items` collection. There's a discussion about that here: [Add new menuitem to menu at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291522/wpf-how-can-you-add-a-new-menuitem-to-a-menu-at-runtime).

The library that was linked above by Shoban looks like a set of classes that do this for you. But, it's for winforms. If you're using wpf, you might have to write your own (though there are probably pre-made ones out there somewhere), but the winforms one will give you a good starting place.

You can also then create jumplists in win7's taskbar using the [Windows API Code Pack for .Net](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack).

Answer (score 1):

Gagan, i have recently made a recent file menu in WPF C# and here is what i did:

-> to enable the jumplist functionality and start menu recent file menu i used the windows API shell routine like this:

[DllImport("shell32.dll")] //shell routine to enable  jumplist and recenfiles
        public static extern void SHAddToRecentDocs(
            UInt32 uFlags,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            String pv);

and call it like this:
 SHAddToRecentDocs(0x00000003, mFilePath);

-> Then to display recent file menu i used an xml file, stored recent files in that and parsed and displayed recent file in the menu.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the **Writer** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. It shows how to use and implement a recent file list which is shown in the file menu and on the start page.