# How to add recently open documents to the OpenRecent menu items in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, jump-list

I had develop an Wpf application which open an .doc file and doing some operations. Now I want to add open recent feature in menu items which shows the list of recently opened document. Now there is a wpf class called jump list but I do not understand how to use the jump list in my application.

Comment: [Jump Lists](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/jump-lists) are available from the task bar. This is what you need ?

Comment: yes...How do I use the Jump Lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [ShowRecentCategory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.jumplist.showrecentcategory(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the JumpList.
When you start the app create the jump list:

```
JumpList jumpList = new JumpList();
jumpList.ShowRecentCategory = true;
JumpList.SetJumpList(Application.Current, jumpList);
```

Then when you want to add a document to the recent list use the [AddToRecentCategory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783498(v=vs.100).aspx) method:

```
JumpList.AddToRecentCategory(/*item path*/);
```

Important to rememer: "*If your application is not registered to handle the file type of the item, it will not appear in the Recent list and calls to AddToRecentCategory(String) will fail silently.*"