# MenuItem with subitems binded to Commands. (MVVM)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, command, menuitem

Have a code like:

```
<MenuItem ItemSource="SOURCE">
   ..sub MenuItems
</MenuItem>
```

How to create the right template that allows to bind the each subitem to the save command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```
<MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
  <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
      <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
    </Style>
  </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it in a project:

In the Window definition i "define" the commands workspace.

```
   <Window x:Class="WorkForce.Views.MainWindow"
    ...
    xmlns:commands="clr-namespace:WorkForce.Commands"
    ...
    >
```

After that I connect them to each menu-item.

```
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Header="_New..." Command="commands:MainWindowCommands.NewFile"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Open..."  Command="commands:MainWindowCommands.OpenFile"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Save..."  Command="commands:MainWindowCommands.SaveFile"/>
        </MenuItem>
```

I hope that is enough

I saw that you want to add it dynamically. Please look at this: [WPF: How can you add a new menuitem to a menu at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291522/wpf-how-can-you-add-a-new-menuitem-to-a-menu-at-runtime)

Comment: The problem is the I have the dinamic source of menu items)